# Installing LuaJava

Tags: java, lua, terminal, makefile, luajava

I have a Mac version 10.9 and I'm trying to build LuaJava. I built Lua 5.0 no problems, but when using [this tutorial](http://retrovirus.com/incr/2005/08/building-luajava/) I get this error:

```
In file included from src/c/luajava.c:39:
src/c/luajava.h:2:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not found
#include <jni.h>
```

from Terminal when I run make. I tracked down the jni header, but now I don't know what to do with it/ where to put it so it finds it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the include problem go away, replace

```
INCS= -I$(JDK)/include -I$(JDK)/include/linux -I$(LUA_INCLUDES)
```

with

```
INCS= -I/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers -I$(LUA_INCLUDES)
```

in the file called `config`